# How to change the html body Theme using Kendo ui html5

Tags: html, web, kendo-ui

I'm new to use Kendoui, HTML 5 for web , i have create one small Demo app in html 5,in this i need to change the Theme by dynamically , means when i select the color from Combo-box or Drop-down it should be apply for entire page. I searched in Google but i did not get right solution , please guide me how to do .

Here is the code what  fallow sample .

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
<title></title>
  <link href="Content/kendo/2013.2.716/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="Content/kendo/2013.2.716/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" typ  e="text/css" />
   <script src="Scripts/kendo/2013.2.716/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/kendo/2013.2.716/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
    html, body
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body
    {
        font: 12px/1.5 Tahoma,sans-serif;
        padding: 2em;
    }

    span.themeChooser
    {
        float: right;
    }

    #tree
    {
        height: 9em;
    }
</style>
  </head>
  <body class="k-content">
      <div id="example" class="k-content">
        <input class="themeChooser" value="default" />
         <div id="tree">
        </div>

      <p>
             Note: in order for the whole page to be styled, the &lt;body&gt; element has a <code>
            k-content</code> class.</p>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#themeChooser").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: [
    { text: "Black", value: "black" },
    { text: "Blue Opal", value: "blueopal" },
    { text: "Default", value: "default" },
    { text: "Metro", value: "metro" },
    { text: "Silver", value: "silver" }
],
            change: function (e) {
                var theme = (this.value() || "default").toLowerCase();

                changeTheme(theme);
            }
        });

        // sample widget on the page
        $("#tree").kendoTreeView({
            dataSource: [
    { text: "foo", expanded: true, items: [
        { text: "bar", selected: true }
      ]
    },
    { text: "baz" }
]
        });

        // loads new stylesheet
        function changeTheme(skinName, animate) {
            var doc = document,
    kendoLinks = $("link[href*='kendo.']", doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]),
    commonLink = kendoLinks.filter("[href*='kendo.common']"),
    skinLink = kendoLinks.filter(":not([href*='kendo.common'])"),
    href = location.href,
    skinRegex = /kendo\.\w+(\.min)?\.css/i,
    extension = skinLink.attr("rel") === "stylesheet" ? ".css" : ".less",
    url = commonLink.attr("href").replace(skinRegex, "kendo." + skinName + "$1" + extension),
    exampleElement = $("#example");

            function preloadStylesheet(file, callback) {
                var element = $("<link rel='stylesheet' media='print' href='" + file + "'").appendTo("head");

                setTimeout(function () {
                    callback();
                    element.remove();
                }, 100);
            }

            function replaceTheme() {
                var oldSkinName = $(doc).data("kendoSkin"),
        newLink;

                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    newLink = doc.createStyleSheet(url);
                } else {
                    newLink = skinLink.eq(0).clone().attr("href", url);
                }

                newLink.insertBefore(skinLink[0]);
                skinLink.remove();

                $(doc.documentElement).removeClass("k-" + oldSkinName).addClass("k-" + skinName);
            }

            if (animate) {
                preloadStylesheet(url, replaceTheme);
            } else {
                replaceTheme();
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Thank you .

Comment: show your code what you done so far.

Comment: I'm fallowing this link http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/index.html. but this is the only for object but i need to change the entire form.

Comment: Change the kendo theme? Or change random css rule colors?

Comment: Thank you for replay .. Is there any sample..? because i don't know how to do .. please ....   Here i found one link http://jsfiddle.net/gyoshev/Gxpfy/   .... when run this i get errors .

Comment: works for me, what error do you get? what browser?

Comment: when click on dropdown it does not show the list items, but if press down arrow then change the theme name but it theme applying.. i chekced in Chrome browser.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. Works fine in chrome for me. Check your javascript console for any errors

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C; IPH 1.1.21.4019; Mailinfo [1786723]; BOIE9;ENUS)
Timestamp: Wed, 4 Sep 2013 14:26:33 UTC


Message: Unable to get value of the property 'opera': object is null or undefined
Line: 11
Char: 1253
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:51035/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36800/discussion-between-ryan-and-victor-athoti)

Comment: @Victor Athoti I think your browser not find the `js` file and `css` path is not find just do it like this `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/kendo.all.min.js")"` type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I think it's just your path problem nothing else.